# Master Toggle for checkbox not working in multiple expanded Mat-Table rows

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a multiple row expandable mat table grid , which fetches data from different API's on each row click . I have a checkbox selection in every row for the inner grid , but the master toggle for the inner grid checkbox doesnt work .

But it works for the outer grid .

[image]

**My inner grid data Source Value is different for each row based on the ID , I guess its because of that . I tried passing ID to the toggle function but it didn't work .**

A snippet of my HTML -

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="usersdataSource[element.Id]" multiTemplateDataRows matSort>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
                <mat-header-cell class="w-40" *matHeaderCellDef>
                        <mat-checkbox color="primary"
                                (change)="$event ? UserMasterToggle() : null"
                                [checked]="userSelection.hasValue() && isAllUserSelected()"
                                [indeterminate]="userSelection.hasValue() && !isAllUserSelected()">
                        </mat-checkbox>
                </mat-header-cell>
```

My TS -

```
  isAllUserSelected() {
const numSelected = this.userSelection.selected.length;
const numRows = this.usersdataSource.data.length;
return numSelected == numRows;
  }

     /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
      UserMasterToggle() {
        this.isAllUserSelected()
          ? this.userSelection.clear()
          : this.usersdataSource.data.forEach(row =>
              this.userSelection.select(row)
            );
      }
```

[I have a working Stackblitz to reproduce this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-dwt8uf?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts) - Can anyone guide me through this ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the fact that you don't manage a list of `userSelection` because you will have as many `userSelection` as the number of expended rows with data.

Here is a [working stackblitz with the issue fixed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-vk3akb).

Comment: Thank you so much  , that worked . Can you look to this similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189074/master-toggle-for-checkbox-not-working-when-datasource-is-set-on-html-element-se

Comment: @OLO can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71267560/select-all-checkboxes-by-default-in-nested-mat-table-not-working-as-expected