# Master toggle for checkbox not working when datasource is set on html element selection

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a similar issue like of the question -

[Master Toggle for checkbox not working in multiple expanded Mat-Table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68183896/master-toggle-for-checkbox-not-working-in-multiple-expanded-mat-table-rows) .

But instead of `this.usersdataSource[element.Id] = new MatTableDataSource(res);` used there , I have used it as `element['usersdataSource'] = new MatTableDataSource(res);`

Now in the solution i see that selectionMap is used -

```
userSelectionMap: Map<number, SelectionModel<any>> = new Map<number,SelectionModel<any>>();

UserMasterToggle(elementId: number) {
this.isAllUserSelected(elementId)
  ? this.userSelectionMap.get(elementId).clear()
  : this.usersdataSource[elementId].data.forEach(row =>
      this.userSelectionMap.get(elementId).select(row)
    );


 }

  isAllUserSSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.userSSelection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.leftPanelDataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected == numRows;
  }
```

How should i use `userSelectionMap: Map<number, SelectionModel<any>> = new Map<number,SelectionModel<any>>();` when i have assigned datasource value to the element value like `element['usersdataSource'] = new MatTableDataSource(res);`

[I have working stackblitz link for my issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-u32tkn?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html) - can anyone please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [working stackblitz link with your issue fixed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-1knrox).

Comment: Thank You @OLO . Can you have a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219670/how-to-read-access-values-inside-a-map-of-selectionmodel-in-angular .